# Why __KVOKeyPathBridgeMachinery.automaticallyNotifiesObservers(forKey:) appears in the backtrace in the KVO crash

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c-runtime

I encountered a crash in old version MMPProgressHUD.m KVO.  The `backtrace` in firebase is as follow:

[image]

Platform:

- Most in the iOS 12, ohters are iOS 11 or iOS 10
  Device:
- The firebase shows the devices are *not* jailbroken

In the newer version, the `MBProgressHUD`, the `KVO` stuff has been removed. What I have to do is to upgrade `MBProgressHUD`. But I wonder why there is `__KVOKeyPathBridgeMachinery.automaticallyNotifiesObservers(forKey:)` in the backtrace. It is from `libSwfitFoundation`.  Because the code context is Objective-C. Besides, when debugging in iPhone 5s, iOS12.4.8, the backtrace uses `[NSObject(NSKeyValueObservingCustomization)automaticallyNotifiesObserversForKey:]` instead, which is for the process of notification changes. [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOCompliance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002178-SW3)

- I set a symbolic breakpoint for `+[NSObject(NSKeyValueObservingCustomization)automaticallyNotifiesObserversForKey:]`
- the symbolic breakpoint for
  `__KVOKeyPathBridgeMachinery.automaticallyNotifiesObservers(forKey:)` hasn't been hit.

```
lldb) bt
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = one-shot breakpoint 16
  * frame #0: 0x0000000227524ca4 Foundation`+[NSObject(NSKeyValueObservingCustomization) automaticallyNotifiesObserversForKey:]
    frame #1: 0x00000002275164c0 Foundation`-[NSKeyValueUnnestedProperty _isaForAutonotifying] + 68
    frame #2: 0x0000000227516374 Foundation`-[NSKeyValueUnnestedProperty isaForAutonotifying] + 104
    frame #3: 0x0000000227514510 Foundation`-[NSObject(NSKeyValueObserverRegistration) _addObserver:forProperty:options:context:] + 412
    frame #4: 0x0000000227513730 Foundation`-[NSObject(NSKeyValueObserverRegistration) addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:] + 124
    frame #5: 0x00000001047141d8 MyApp `-[MMPProgressHUD registerForKVO](self=0x0000000112575d60, _cmd="registerForKVO") at MMPProgressHUD.m:669:3
    frame #6: 0x000000010471064c MyApp`-[MMPProgressHUD initWithFrame:](self=0x0000000112575d60, _cmd="initWithFrame:", frame=(origin = (x = 0, y = 0), size = (width = 320, height = 568))) at MMPProgressHUD.m:205:3
    frame #7: 0x0000000104710834 MyApp `-[MMPProgressHUD initWithView:](self=0x0000000000000000, _cmd="initWithView:", view=0x00000001125ae4d0) at MMPProgressHUD.m:213:9
    frame #8: 0x000000010470f874 MyApp `+[MMPProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:animated:](self=SHPUIProgressHUD, _cmd="showHUDAddedTo:animated:", view=0x00000001125ae4d0, animated=YES) at MMPProgressHUD.m:117:24
```

---

It looks like it is an issue in Swift4.0

https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/20103#issuecomment-435558912

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is part of the stuff that makes KVO work: https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-01-23.html

Comment: Is `MMPProgressHUD ` related to `MBProgressHUD`? There is no `registerForKVO` in that class, did you add that in your subclass?

Comment: Yes, it turns out the MBProgressHUD in our company's codebase is too old. The version is 0.9, still has `registerForKVO` there.

Comment: That version is several years old, can you upgrade to the latest (1.2 I think) ?

Comment: I think so, thanks.